# Denormalization influence on code

Tags: database, denormalization

I am a product owner. My company has a denormalized database due to technical debt. I want to try and change that at least for future development. I have a question for one of my arguments. In the database the translations for article descriptions are stored in the same table as the article. The fieldnames are "desc_English", "desc_Spanish" etc.

I want to point out that you need to compare strings in the code for matching the fieldname. Which in my imagination leads to blurry, hard to maintain and slower code. I've seen if statements of 1400 lines to match text strings on other topics.

Is this a valid argument or are there simple ways to bypass this problem with enums or something?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a normalised/denormalised database model is a fundamental decision in database design and it is primarily based on the type of system desired to be built i.e. transaction (OLTP) vs. reporting (OLAP).

Problem you describe seems to stem from bad code rather than the database modeling technique used to build the database.